# Why does "chrome.runtime.onInstalled" event fire without new installations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a problem with my chrome extension analytics. I tried looking for similar questions but didn't find anyone with a similar issue.

The onInstalled event in my code is getting fired without getting new installations. Neither my analytics (which tracks the "track_install/" url) nor the Chrome Web Store analytics show this number of new installations. We are speaking about more than 10x difference in the number of new installations per CWS or analytics VS the number of times onInstalled is fired, and this behaviour is consistent for months in my case.

Anybody else experienced this behavior?

Here is how my code looks like:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    if(details.reason == "install"){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'install', 'extension installed']);
        setUninstallUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled): _"Fired when the extension is first installed, when the extension is updated to a new version, and when Chrome is updated to a new version."_

Comment: @Andreas as far as i know specifying "details.reason=='install'" limits it to only installs?

Comment: It can't happen without the extension actually being installed. That would be a bug in Chrome. I think it's a bug in CWS stats as I've seen several reports recently saying that stats are frozen for weeks or even longer.

Comment: I think it’s a problem with the event. As i mentioned the difference exceeds 10x and if even a quarter of that number of fired oninstalled events was installations, it will be reflected in the weekly active users. Also my extension is a paid one, so new installations get reflected in payments too. So obviously this event gets fired for some reason that i cant figure out

Comment: Then it can only be a bug in the browser or the users are actually reinstalling the extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Doh! I just saw this was in 2019. Never mind. I'm curious on how you solved it, though.

I'm rather new to javascript. But I found this example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/)

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((reason) => {
    if (reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'onboarding.html'
      });
    }
  });
```

I don't get why your code would work, but it seems strange to me that you are able to get any data from `details.reason`. Not sure how the enum is returned, though.

Another not very notable difference is the `===` in my example, whereas you use `==`. I my limited understanding the type should be the same and this doesn matter.

Anyway, I can't be of much help, I think. I hope you are able to figure it out.